# How to convert layers of many-to-one relationships into input data without losing information?

Tags: data-structures, data-science

I apologize if the question doesn't make much sense.
I'm trying to convert data into inputs for a classifier. I have multiple layers of many to one data which I need to "attach" to the top layer. I will try to explain with an example:

Let's say you have a household, each household contains at least one person (represented with categorical data male/female/other), each person has some amount of pets (represented with categorical data dog/cat/rat/etc..). Is it possible to represent this data into one row (for the household) without losing information?

One way I could think of doing it was the count of the amount of data for each category, so a household would have 2 males, 1 female, 2 dogs and 1 cat. Except this loses the information about how the data itself is structured, like if the female has all of the pets, that data doesn't tell you that.

The other way would be structuring each household into a database, so each row is a person containing m/f/o and the amount of each pet, then performing some dimensionality reduction technique to put it all on one row for the household but I'm not sure if this is feasible.

So yeah, any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: There are tons of possible ways to represent that data. Depends what kind of classifier you want to run on it afterwards.

Comment: Right now I'm just using a neural network. The output data is categorical. Can you give me some examples of how to represent it?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using the one-hot-encoding method to represent each on a single line? Or does this method work?

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame({'household':["M","M","F","M","F","F"],
                   'pets': ["Cat","Dog","Cat","Hamster","Dog","Cat"],
                  'amount of pets': [2,1,1,2,2,3]})

df=pd.get_dummies(df,columns=["pets"])
print(df)

  household  amount of pets  pets_Cat  pets_Dog  pets_Hamster
0         M               2         1         0             0
1         M               1         0         1             0
2         F               1         1         0             0
3         M               2         0         0             1
4         F               2         0         1             0
5         F               3         1         0             0

print(df.iloc[:1])

 household  amount of pets  pets_Cat  pets_Dog  pets_Hamster
0         M               2         1         0             0
```

In this way, it is possible to see both the animal owned by the household and its number in a single line. Is this the representation you want?

Comment: Maybe I'm misreading the table but it looks like each row is a representation of each person and the amounts of their pets instead of the household. 

There's multiple people in each household and each person has multiple pets and I want a representation where it's a database of households, each row containing the data representing the most information about who owns what pet.